# Scipy randint vs numpy randint

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

I have a simple yet broad question regarding two methods:

```
scipy.stats.randint
```

and

```
numpy.random.randint
```

After reading the API for both methods I'm a bit confused as to when it is best to use each method; therefore, I was wondering if someone could outline the differences between the two and possibly offer some examples of when one method would be preferable to use over the other. Thanks!

Edit: Links to each method's documentation -> [numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html),  [scipy.stats.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html)

Answer (score 2):

The major difference seems to be that `scipy.stats.randint` allows you to explicitly name the lower or upper tail probability, as well as specify the distributions you want to draw the random ints from (see the methods section of the [scipy.stats.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html) documentation). It's therefore much more useful if you want to draw random intervals from a given density function.

If you really just want to draw a random integer that falls within a certain range, with no requirements regarding the distribution, then `numpy.random.randint` is more straightforward. They would be drawn directly from a discrete uniform distribution, with no built in option to modify that.

Comment: Oh yes I see that now! And I see that there are methods you can perform on the scipy randint and the numpy randint simply returns a random integer or an array of random integers. Okay interesting. Follow-up question then, is the scipy randint a class? of which you instantiate an object?

Comment: *"Follow-up question then, is the scipy randint a class? of which you instantiate an object?"* No, `scipy.stats.randint` is an instance of the class `scipy.stats.randint_gen`.  `scipy.stats.randint` is ready to use--you can call its methods without instantiating any additional objects.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I see that now in the source code, thanks. For anyone else who is curious they can find randint being initialized [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py)